# Chrome doesn't reflect any DOM changes within onbeforeunload handler

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I can see, that since the Chrome 51, not only you cannot set a custom exit confirmation message, but neither you can make any changes to DOM. You can, but there's no reflow/repainting before you click "Stay".

I couldn't find this documented anywhere on the net, so I need a confirmation, that this is an expected behaviour and I have a little hope that there is a workaround for this.

And here's a plunker, where I get "Goodbye" only when clicking "Stay".

https://plnkr.co/edit/DMNRPkhvNtNU2SxzeKh4

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    Hello
    <script>
      window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
        document.body.innerHTML = "Goodbye";
        var dialogText = 'Dialog text here';
        e.returnValue = dialogText;
        return dialogText;
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't have an answer for you but I am seeing the same behavior with Chrome 52 and Chrome 53, as well.

Comment: Actually, this _may_ have to do with "Pause Event Loop During Modal Dialogs (https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5683408571203584)", though that page states that it was introduced in Chrome 52, not 51 as you reported.

Comment: @SteveJ seems very much like it!